# woocommerce_payment_complete hook only called after accepting payment?

Tags: plugins

Is there a particular paypal setting that allows WooCommerce to execute `woocommerce_payment_complete` without manually accepting the payment? I have a function that hooks on it. It basically updates a record in the database once the client has finished purchasing the product. Thoughts?

Comment: Not fully sure what you're asking but the IPN from Paypal should already trigger a payment complete on your site automatically when a payment is made without any manual processing.

Comment: Yeah that's what I understood. What's puzzling is the hook is triggered if I switch to sandbox mode.